# Google Map API - displaying night mode without lines or green

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-styling

I want to use google maps for one application. I wanted to show the map in night mode. (Dark background for the countries.) I do not want to show any labels, lines, green effect. Just plain countries in night mode. These are the style settings I use.

```
var styleSettings = [
        {
            featureType: 'all',
            stylers : [
                {invert_lightness: 'true'},
                {visibility: 'simplified'}
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "all",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [{visibility: 'simplified'}]
        },
        {
            featureType: "road",
            elementType: "geometry",
            stylers: [{visibility: 'true'}]
        }
        ];
```

Then I create a Map and assign this options.

```
map.setOptions ({styles: styleSettings});
```

I am still getting lines and green spots. How can i avoid those?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting visibility to simplified or true when you don't want to display these things? Set visibility to off. Also, you may want to disable the POIs:

```
[{
    featureType:"poi",
    elementType:"labels",
    stylers:[{
        visibility:"off"
    }]
}]
```